# Making Prime number

Tags: prime-numbers

i know there is a Command in Matematica to get prime number, but i want to break down the code,here is what i got

```
Clear[a, b, n]
a=For[n = 2, n <= 19, If[Mod[n, 2] < 1 , , Print[n]], n++];
b=For[n = 2, n <= 19, If[Mod[n, 3] < 1 , , Print[n]], n++];
Slice[a, b]
```

and the result is
3
5
7
9
11
13
15
17
19
4
5
7
8
10
11
13
14
16
17
19
20

i want to slice it but i dont know how
i want the result be 5 7 11 13 17 19

Comment: `Prime[Range[10]] == 
 Rest[Cases[FactorInteger[Range[30]], 
   x_?(Length[#] == 1 && #[[1, 2]] == 1 &) :> x[[1, 1]]]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean `Intersection`? The problem here is that with `For`, you get return value `Null` for both `a` and `b`. And of course `Slice` is not a Mathematica command. Try this instead:

```
Select[
 Select[Range[2, 19], ! Divisible[#, 2] &],
 ! Divisible[#, 3] &
 ]
```

Or this:

```
Intersection[
 Pick[Range[2, 19], Divisible[Range[2, 19], 2], False],
 Pick[Range[2, 19], Divisible[Range[2, 19], 3], False]
 ]
```

Or this:

```
Pick[
 Range[2, 19],
 Times @@ Table[
   Unitize[Mod[Range[2, 19], k]],
   {k, 2, 3}
   ],
 1
 ]
```

Answer (score 2):

The version of Mathematica I have do not have `Slice` command and never seen this in Mathematica? But assuming you want to capture the output in separate lists, you can try

```
Clear[a,b,n]
a=Flatten@Rest@Reap@For[n=2,n<=19,
   If[Mod[n,2]<1, 
     ,
     Sow@n
   ],
   n++
];

b=Flatten@Rest@Reap@For[n=2,n<=19,
    If[Mod[n,3]<1,
      ,
      Sow@n
    ],
    n++
];
```

And now

```
{a, b}
```

gives

```
{{3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19},{4,5,7,8,10,11,13,14,16,17,19,20}}
```

There are much better ways to do this. You can replace `For` by `Do` for example, and you can do all of this in a more functional way in Mathematica. But this is for another topic.

**ps. Based on edit**, you can now just do

```
 Intersection[a, b]
```

which gives

```
 {5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19}
```

Comment: i already edit my question, i hope you understand